# Wave-like equation with 1st order time derivative and non-constant coefficients

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

We start with the following recurrence relation for complex coefficients $c_{n,m}$:
$$i\dot{c}_{n,m}(t) = \sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)(m-1)m}c_{n-2,m+2} + \sqrt{n(n-1)(m+1)(m+2)}c_{n+2,m-2}$$
where $\dot{c}_{n,m}$ denotes time derivative and $n,m = 0,1,2,...$.

In order to solve this equation and find the time evolution of $c_{n,m}$ (we assume that at $t=0$ we know values of $c_{n,m}$) we define a generation function:
$$G(x,y,t) = \sum\limits_{n,m=0}^{\infty}x^{n}y^{m}\alpha_{n,m}c_{n,m}(t)$$
with some unknown coefficient $\alpha_{n,m}$ that can be adjusted manually. Recurrence relation can be rewritten in terms of differential equation for $G$:
$$i\partial_{t}G(x,y,t) = (y^2\partial_{x}^2 + x^2\partial_{y}^2)G(x,y,t)$$
if we set
$$\alpha_{n,m} = \alpha_{n+2,m-2}\sqrt{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{m(m-1)}}$$
We can assume that $G(x,y,0)$ is known and converges in the domain $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ for any $t$.

Is there a way to find function $G(x,y,t)$ that is not represented by infinite series? This is a special kind of Schrödinger equation.

Comment: Minor comment: it is not a diffusion equation. It is a Schrodinger equation with variable coefficients.

Comment: Are you sure your recursion relation is stated correctly?  I think that, in the first term on the right hand side, you should have a $c_{n-2,m+2}$, not $c_{n-2,m-2}$.  Note that the problem completely uncouples into a sequence of finite recursion problems because for a fixed sum $s = m+n$ and (even-odd) parity of $m-n$, the set of such $c_{n,m}$ (and this is a finite set of such, since you are assuming that $n,m\ge0$) only interacts with itself.  Thus, you really should be thinking in terms of these finite recursion problems.  It's really a collection of finite dimensional eigenvalue problems.

Comment: @RobertBryant Indeed there was a mistake in recursion relation. This is a physics problem and as you noticed coefficient $c_{n,m}$ is linked with others such that $s=n+m$ is fixed. We can of course find eigenvalues for small $s$ and find time evolution explicitly. However this doesn't solve my problem cause imagine I want to know what happens when $s$ is large and theoretically tends to infinity.

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich: I understand that you want to know 'what happens' for large values of $s$, but, depending on what you mean by 'what happens', I am skeptical that you will learn more by any technique than by figuring out the asymptotics of the distribution of the eigenvalues in terms of $s$.  At least you know that, for each $s$, the eigenvalues of $L=y^2\partial_x^2+x^2\partial_y^2$ on $H_s$, the homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$ of total degree $s$, are real, symmetrical about 0, and have multiplicity $2$ when $s$ is odd and multiplicity $1$ when $s$ is even. Do you know any asymptotics?